# Internet Explorer truncating flashVars containing JSON

Tags: string, json, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, flashvars

This only happens in IE.

I'm using *swfobject* and loading the flash vars as such

```
var flashVars = {
       myVar:'{"url":"http://google.com/", "id":"9999"}',
};
var params = {
    allowFullScreen:"true",
    wmode:"transparent",
    allowScriptAccess:'always'
    };
swfobject.embedSWF("mySwf.swf", "mySwf", "512", "318", "10.0.0", "./js/swfobject/expressInstall.swf", flashVars, params);
```

Everything works perfectly in all browser but IE. I checked `myVar` and it comes into the swf as `{` and that's it. I know it's dying at the `'`. I've tried putting a `\` infront, then tried `\\` and kept adding one slash until I got to `\\\\\\\\`. I even inverted all the slashes and tried the same ritual. Nothing.

I can get the string to finally come through, with inverted quotes and using double slashes, but then my JSON parser gets mad about there being slashes in my string.

Here's an example of what works, but of what is invalid JSON:

```
"{\\'url\\':\\'http://google.com/\\', \\'id\\':\\'9999\\'}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep IE treats flashVars differently to all the other major browsers, I believe you need to make use of the JavaScript [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method which will escape all reserved characters from your String, eg:

```
// Removing all reserved characters from the flashVar value.
var flashVars = {
   myVar: encodeURIComponent('{"url":"http://google.com/", "id":"9999"}'),
};
```

If you are passing multiple values in the flashVars then you could iterate through them and encode all chars in a single pass:

```
var flashVars = {
   myVar: '{"url":"http://google.com/", "id":"9999"}',
   anotherVar: 42
};

// Escape all values contained in the flashVars object.
for (key in flashVars) {
    if (flashVars.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        flashVars[key] = encodeURIComponent(flashVars[key]);
    }
}
```

As @dgmdan and @bcmoney suggested, it would probably make your code easier to read if you made use of `JSON.stringify` - however, you need to bear in mind that IE8 and below *do not* have a native JSON object, so you will need to include [Crockford's JS Library](http://www.json.org/js.html) in your HTML page.

```
// Making use of a JSON library.
var flashVars = {
   myVar: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ url: "http://google.com/", id: "9999"})),
};
```

Also, it's worth bearing in mind that flashVars are limited to ~64k; so if you are planning to pass a lot of data, it might be better to use an `ExternalInterface` call to pull them from the JavaScript instead.

Comment: I switched to external interface and everything is working fine now. However, it's not because of the 64k limit. I'll have to try the 1encodeURIComponent1 though to so how that goes. Thanks for the pro answer!

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/json), native JSON is available for IE8

Answer (score 0):

Try this to replace your first 3 lines:

```
var subVars = { url: "http://google.com/", id: "9999" };
var flashVars = { myVar: JSON.stringify(subVars) };
```